# Solve for $x$ in $0 = e^{x^2} (2x)$

Tags: calculus

$$0 = e^{x^2} (2x)$$

How do I solve for x?

**Attempt**: Divide both sides by $2x$

$$0 = e^{x^2}$$

Do I simply continue to divide until $x = 0$?

Comment: since u can't take ln of 0

Comment: Hint: zero product rule...

Comment: @String never heard of it...care to elaborate?

Comment: You can't just divide by $2x$ - what if $x=0$? Indeed, $x=0$ is a solution to $2xe^{x^2}=0$

Comment: You can only divide by $2x$ if you know that $2x \neq 0$. And in your last expression, $x^2 > 0$ so $e^{x^2} > e^0 = 1$.

Comment: @Jessica: You could look it up, but basically it states that a product is zero if and only if one of the factors is zero...

Comment: so how do you get to zero?

Comment: So either $e^{x^2}=0$ OR $2x=0$. Pick the one that serves you the best ;)

Comment: @Jessica: But that said, I can see that you have a misunderstanding regarding the notion of the exponential function and exponentiation in general... A number raised to ANY power is never zero, so there is no way that $\mbox{e}^{x^2}$ can be zero.

Comment: @Jessica: Elaborating a bit on that about the concept of exponentiation, note that exponents are build upon the idea of multiplying and dividing by the base number, in this case it is $\mbox{e}\approx 2.718281828459$, so either multiplying by this or dividing by this you will never get zero....

Comment: @String Thank you so much, i never really looked at it like that, however i still don't understand how to simplify the e^x^2 = 0 given that i can't take ln of zero...

Comment: @String can i just deem it not possible and call it a day? :)

Comment: @Jessica: Regarding your attempt to have $\mbox{e}^{x^2}$ to equal zero, sure let's call it a day. But the other factor $2x$ which you so 'prematurely' removed by dividing by it has all potential in the world to become zero thus making your product zero (in full accordance with the said zero product rule). So what must $x$ be if $2x$ (the double of it) equals zero?

Comment: @String it's rather unfortunate since x was going towards such great things. well, naturally and intuitively x can now become zero yaaay

Comment: @Jessica: Perfect! The socratic method has won again ;)

Comment: @String Haha thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The product of two "things" is zero if and only if one of the factors is zero:
$$
ab = 0 \iff a = 0 \text{ or } b = 0
$$
so
$$
(2x)e^{x^2} = 0 \iff 2x = 0 \text{ or } e^{x^2} = 0.
$$
Now the exponential function is never zero, so ...

Comment: so...its impossible?

Comment: @Jessica: No. What is means is that the solution(s) to your equation is/are the same solution(s) so the equation $2x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1 You have to be careful about dividing by zero

2 Assuming $x$ is a real number, consider the graph of the exponential function

Answer (score 1):

There are two seperate cases to investigate: $x=0$ and $x\not=0$ respectively.

1. **Suppose $x\not=0$**: then it is OK for you to divide away $2x$ and find $$\exp(x^2)=0,$$ which never happens for real $x$. This means that there are no solutions to the original equation for $x\not=0$.
2. Now **suppose that $x=0$**. Well then you get $0=0$ which is true. Thus $x=0$ is the **only solution**.

Comment: $e^x\ne 0$ for complex $x$ as well.

Comment: Yes, but I never implied that it did either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean $2xe^{x^2} = 0$ ?
If so, since $e^x > 0$ for all $x$, we have only $x=0$ as a solution.

You can't divide by $x$ unless you specify $x\neq 0$, so you can't divide by $x$ and then say : "Oh ! $x=0$ is a solution !"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose x is not zero: then you can divide away 2x and find
exp(xx)=0,
which never happens for real x.